# Visual Studio Code не запускает код, а IDLE от Python - запускает

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Пробовал переустановить - не помогло

```
import tkinter as tk

windows = tk.Tk ()
windows.geometry(f"300x100")
windows.title("text")
label_1 = tk.Label (windows, text ="text",
                    bg = "black",
                    fg = "white",
                    font =("Arial", 20, "bold"),
                    )
label_1.pack()
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: А VSCode тут при чем?

Comment: я хочу запускать код в vs

Comment: вот и интересно в чем может быть проблема

Comment: прочитайте документацию и последней строкой добавьте такую `windows.mainloop()`

Comment: спасибо огромное, это помогло